# Create Instagram-esque filters with javascript?

Tags: javascript, image-processing, node.js

Can I create Instagram-esque filters with javascript?

The images can be processed client-side or server-side(node.js)

I could overlay some pngs and box-shadows with css to get a limited amount of similar effects, but I was wondering if there was anything out there that can truly process images like this in js.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up finding this, http://vintagejs.com/

Answer (score 6):

Alex Michael has a fantastic open source javascript library for instagram filters:
http://alexmic.github.com/filtrr/

Comment: This looks very nice.

Comment: just redirection to site. Not a git repo

Answer (score 3):

You could do it with canvas. See :

[Making Image Filters with Canvas](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/imagefilters/)

[Pixastic Image Processing Library](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/)

Answer (score 0):

I think all filters are public libs wrote in C/C++ that u can import in node =) Give a try