# Looking for high-level Instagram/Microsoft Word like image processing library

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, image-processing

Currently, I am looking for a (commercial or free) .NET/C# image processing library for a WinForms project to apply customizable effects like Instagram or Microsoft Office Word does, e.g.:

[image]

I found plenty of image libraries like:

- [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)
- [Lead Tools](http://www.leadtools.com/)
- [Free Image](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/)
- [DotImage](https://www.atalasoft.com/products/dotimage-sdk-1)
- ...

Unfortunately, all these libraries seem to provide a rather low-level way of manipulating images. When it comes to high-level effects like borders, rotation, vintage filters like Instagram, etc., I found zero libraries.

(Ironically, for JavaScript, [there are quite a few libraries out there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192317/create-instagram-esque-filters-with-javascript))

Maybe there is no market for such a library, still I would love to have this function in my application without doing everything on my own.

**Therefore my question is:**

Is there a .NET library available to have a customizable and extendable way of applying various high-level filters to images?

Comment: Sorry, Uwe, but asking for resources is off-topic, you know? It falls under the "Chatty and open-ended" portion of the FAQ.

Comment: @Oded - I've read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) before posting, I thought "software tools commonly used by programmers" includes libraries. Am I wrong?

Comment: It is, but asking for recommendations is always off-topic (not constructive), as these can change over time and the answers are pretty much always subjective.

Comment: @Oded Thanks. Any other Stack Exchange site ([Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) maybe?) to ask this question?

Comment: The only Stack Exchange that I know accepts recommendation questions is Tex. By all means, bring it up on Meta (though I suggest doing some research on this before hand).

Comment: this question is constructive. I have the same question. Sometimes SO sucks!