# Freeware to generate MSBuild file

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, build, msbuild

Does anyone know of any good freeware to generate an MSBuild file? I'm using VS 2010 and have a web site (not web application) so there is no .csproj file.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/735054/how-to-convert-asp-net-website-to-asp-net-web-application

Comment: I really wonder why [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13270031/107625) regarding a library recommendation gets closed while this (similar IMO) question seems to be totally valid.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard good things about MSBuild Explorer. It might be something for you to look at!

- [MSBuildExplorer](http://www.msbuildexplorer.com/)