# Image manipulation in hybrid mobile apps

Tags: image-processing, cordova, titanium, hybrid-mobile-app, icenium

i'd like to ask if there is possibility to write sth like instagram app but not as native application, just hybrid app (titanium or phonegap with ui frameworks)?

Most of functionality for me is possible to implement, but i wonder about image manipulation.
I have experience in appcelerator titanium and icenium(cordova with kendoui) and my idea is to create app in titanium with webview where i will use some JS manipulation scripts, i've found pixastic.com and CamanJS.com(camanjs is not possible to implement i thing in my situation) so pixastic seems the best.. or any other ideas?

What do you think about performance of this solution? Any experiences about this issue? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this post right here: [Create Instagram-esque filters with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192317/create-instagram-esque-filters-with-javascript) sounds like it could direct you in the right way.